# Java Thread : How to access amethod using Thread

Tags: multithreading

I have a java method for downloading a file form URL.
Example,

```
private void(String info){
}
```

I need to call this method using thread.How to access a method using thread.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could make the function `static` and call it inside the thread:

```
ClassName.downloadFile("info...");
```

BTW: you forgot your function name.

You could also create a object:

```
ClassName yourClass = new ClassName();
```

and in your thread (yourClass has to be final in the thread.):

```
yourClass.downloadFile("info...");
```